# Como extraigo un número específico de una columna en R y lo sumo con otro número específico de la misma columna

Tags: r, rstudio

Buenas esperando que se encuentren bien explico mi tarea:
Gracias a la librería quantmod extraje datos de acciones de distintas marcas, el tema es que tengo que tomar un número de una columna en especifico y sumarlo con otro numero, adjunto data:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Especificamente es la columna "AMD.Open" de ella debo extraer por ejemplo el primer numero y sumarlo con el segundo y no sé como hacerlo.
estaba tratando de hacer lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me arroja un número.

Sinceramente no sé como seguir, si me dan algún consejo se agradecería!

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola Diego!

Como tus datos están en un objeto tipo `data.frame` o `matrix`, son dos las dimensiones que tienes que utilizar para referirte a un elemento. Así, tienes dos alternativas

```
# Suma como elementos de matriz
  AMD[1,1] + AMD[1,2

# Suma llamando a la columna correspondiente
  AMD$AMD.Open[1] + AMD$AMD.Open[2]
```

Saludos,